# Test callback function on prop in parent stateless component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, enzyme, jestjs

I am wondering how I can test `renderItem` callback function in the code. My coverage stats say function is not covered and neither is the data it returns.

```
const List = ({ data, dataKey, extraData }) => (
    <FlatList  
          data={data}
          renderItem=({ item }) => <Text>{item[dataKey]}</Text>
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    />);
```

Testing component as follows

```
describe('Test List PureComponent', () => {
    it('renders as expected', () => {
        const baseProps = {
            data: listTestData,
            extraData: { state: '' },
            dataKey: 'name'
        };
        const wrapper = shallow(<List {...baseProps} />);
        expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

I am testing using jest and enzyme. I use shallow to do snapshot test but in the coverage stats I get that callback function for `renderItem` and the return statement are not covered.
This also happens for keyExtractor prop.

I am wondering how I can cover those callbacks in my List component?

Comment: I am pretty sure the coverage shows only the first Line i.e FlatList as covered, it you want to make sure that the renderItem and keyExtractor are covered just separate them out into function and call them from here. Also I believe the syntax of renderItem prop is incorrect,you need to wrap it within `{}`

Comment: I don't like how that code looks. Is it actually showing something on screen? Probably you are not calling the function correctly in the tests and the data is empty. Can you show your tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the `renderItem` and `keyExtractor` out of the component and test them separately.

You can snapshot test the `List` and `ListItem` components, and unit test `keyExtractor` as normal.

```
const ListItem = (item, dataKey) => <Text>{item[dataKey]}</Text>

const keyExtractor = (item, index) => index

const List = ({ data, dataKey, extraData }) => (
    <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ data }) => ListItem(data, dataKey)}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    />
```

Comment: Snapshot testing could work for ListItem function but was still not covered, I had to test as follows

Comment: What exactly do  you assert on the ListItem function?  Can you post some sample test on how you would test the returned component?